# Where can I find information on exactly what Windows KB supersedes another?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-update, updates

I'm going through and updating scripts which I have that will update a Windows 7 Professional installation up to the latest available version with hotfixes.

The issue I'm encountering is when I go back and check against some hotfixes, Windows will allow me to install them but the relevant KB article suggests that they have been superseded.

For example, I have updated IE11 using `IE11-Windows6.1-x64-en-us.exe` and applied hotfixes `KB3185319` and `KB3185319`. Windows Update says that everything is now up to date and no additional hotfixes are available for this application. However, Windows will allow to to install `IE11-Windows6.1-KB3008923-x64.msu` whose [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3008923) states:

> The update that this article describes has been replaced by a newer update. We recommend that you install the most current cumulative security update for Internet Explorer. To install the most current update, go to the following Microsoft website.

According to Windows Update I already have the latest cumulative update but I am still allowed to install this update. Is it related to the several "non-security-related fixes" included in `KB3008923`?

Relying upon the associated KB articles is not always reliable either. For example, `KB3058515` can be applied even while up to date with no associated footnote in its [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/3058515) suggesting that it was ever superseded.

This is an issue with a number of hotfixes and I can't find a clear answer on how to clarify whether they are still applicable. It is sometimes possible to use the [Microsoft Update Catalog](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/home.aspx) as a cross-reference for identifying which update has superseded another but there are cases such as this where attempting to locate the associated entry provides no results.

I have two questions here: if this update has been superseded, why does Windows allow me to install it? How can I identify exactly which hotfix supersedes another from a reliable and authoritative source?

Comment: i'm no expert and I use chrome  and don't really update things that much on my personal computer but IE I understand is an old browser. .If you are so concerned about updates why not use Microsoft Edge? You could even maybe uninstall IE if you think it's a security hazard!   And if windows says everything is up to date then why care about anything re updates?!

Comment: IE11 as it relates to the question is simply an example of the problem not a recommendation on how to browse the web.

Comment: Since Windows 7 lifecycle ended January, 2020, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-7 , unless you have a volume licensed subscription, why bother to update at all? If you have a clone of the last version, there would be *very* few changes after 2020. Or just switch to a modern OS.

Comment: Superseded means just that, no need to install the older one. "How can I identify exactly which hotfix supersedes another from a reliable and authoritative source?" That would be Microsoft.

Comment: @Moab The KB article states that it has been superseded. Windows should not allow me to install a hotfix which is no longer applicable. I want to know which update supersedes this one to confirm that I have in fact patched the vulnerability.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I want to be up to date with not only the latest security release but also to correct additional non-security related problems which may be corrected by these hotfixes. See the linked KB articles.

Answer (score 0):

You did quite a good research already.

The information what you're looking for is not publicly available and - considering Windows 7 is not supported - unlikely Microsoft would help with your problem.